# SSRS Report not setting dropdown list from parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dropdown

I have an SSRS report that has 2 parameters - vendor and years. Years is just a text field while the Vendor is a dropdown list which is generated from a query. I am trying to run this report from another report by passing in values for both of these parameters as below:

http:///ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Production/Supply+Chain/Vendor+Part+History&years=3&vendor=00046

The value of the years parameter is setting correctly but the vendor is not getting selected in the dropdown and hence the report will not run without user having to manually select the vendor.

Can you please advise what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to check.

You are passing in the value `00046` as the vendor therefore either the available values shoudl not be defined in the report or it must include `00046` as one of the available values.

When you pass in a parameter you are passing in the parameter `Value` not the parameter `Label`. So if you had a list of available values from a table something like

| CategoryID | CategoryName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Fruit |
| 2 | Veg |
| 3 | Meat |

and in your parameter's available values you had `CategoryID` as the `Value` and `CategoryName` as the `Label` and you wanted to run the report for "Veg" then you would pass in `2` not Veg .

If your parameter's labels and values are the same, then make sure that they are exactly what you are passing in (i.e. `46` is different than `00046`).

Try setting your parameter type to text, even if it is a number.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Alan. My vendor field has vendorID as the value and Vendor Name as the label - I am passing in the ID (00046 in my example) which is a text field. It is definitely in the list but is not getting pre-selected. Does the fact that the list is generated from a query have anything to do with it - does the report try and match the parameter to the list before the query has executed?

Comment: Parameter queries are executed first unless there is a dependency on a another parameter. If oyu run the report on it own, are any other parameters populated by default, or do any other parameters need to be populated before the Vendor parameter can be set? If you can't fix it, EDIT your question and post your report design, list all the parameters and their settings in as much detail as you can.